# No output when running jar from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, logging, jar

I am running a jar-file in a shell script calling hierarchy. I want to redirect the output from executing the jar file to my logfile "loga.log" but this does only work when I run this script with "sh"-command.

My calling hierarchy basically looks like this:

**Script A calls script B with:**

```
/path/to/script/scriptb.sh &> /path/to/logs/loga.log
```

**Script B calls script C with:**

```
/path/to/script/scriptc.sh > /path/to/logs/logb.log
```

**Script C executes jar-file with:**

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1280m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /path/to/jar/thejar.jar > /path/to/logs/stdout.log #2>/path/to/logs/stderr.log
```

**The first script is started by command line with:**

```
sh /path/to/scripts/scripta.sh
```

and then I get written my output as wanted to the loga.log-file. When I start the script via:

```
/path/to/scripts/scripta.sh
```

this doesn't work and the output is displayed in the console. Unfortunately I am not able to use the sh command because these scripts must be triggered by a UC4-job system which calls this script without using sh. Calling the second script using "sh" inside the first one doesn't work eigther.

How can I edit the scripts to be able to log all output to the specified logfile when running the first one via the above command (without sh)?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: The scripts are all functional and do what they should. I only have problems getting the logging output.

Comment: I am running these on a red hat linux server.